# How to push tags input array in form using angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, firebase, tags

This is my angular HTML code:

```
<form [formGroupName]="form" (ngSubmit)=submitValue()>
     <div *ngFor="let pill of pills" class="pill">{{pill}} <span (click)="removePill(pill)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span></div>
     <input class="keywordsInput" [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="changeValue($event)" formControlName ="Keywords" type="text">
     <button type="submit" class="proceedBtn">Proceed to Submission</button>
</form>
```

It's my typescript code:

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

pills : any[]=[];
value!:string;
list: string[] = [];
filteredList!: string[];

Form!: FormGroup;

FormUpload() {
    this.Form = this.formBuilder.group({
     ...
     Keywords: [this.pills, [Validators.required],
     ...,
    })
  }

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.FormUpload();
  }

  submitValue() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }  

  @HostListener('keyup', ['$event']) keyUp = (e: any) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      this.addPill(e.target.value);
      this.value = ''
    }
  }
  
  removePill(value: string) {
    this.pills = this.pills.filter(x => x !== value);
  }
  
  addPill(value: string) {
    if (!this.pills.find(x => x === value)) {
      this.pills.push(value);
    }
  }
  
  changeValue(val: string) {
    this.doSearch(val);
    this.value = val;
  }
  
  doSearch(term: string) {
    this.filteredList = term && term.length > 1 ? this.list.filter(x => x.includes(term)) : [];
  }
```

Here I'm getting tag input from my HTML and save this tag input into the array of pills variable. Then assign this pills variable to formControlName i.e. keywords. After submitting form values the keywords value is null.

How to fix this issue?
Thank you

Comment: I don't immediately see where you are submitting the form values to Firebase, nor what is going wrong in the code. Can you point out exactly what line in the code is not doing what you expect it dto do?

Comment: I just use a function and console it the form value. It shows the keywords value is null or empty

Comment: I want to send the keywords array of values to the firebase.

Comment: Without seeing the code that gets the form values and sends it to Firebase, it'll be hard to say where you are going wrong. Please edit your question to show the [minimal, complete/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Here i changed my minimal code. Just the assign the array of values to the formControlName (i.e. keywords). Submit the values and check into the console.

Comment: I still don't see any interaction with Firebase. Does the problem occur on the code as is, without using Firebase?

Comment: When i push the form to firebase it shows the keywords value is null. That's why i put it on console to check the value is filled or whether not.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/tag-input-test?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html check this stackblitz. I used this on my code.

Comment: How to assign the pills value to the formControlName keywords